# Julia: UndefVarError: randperm not defined

Tags: julia, permutation

I am currently staring with Julia 1.0.0 under Windows 10. When using a function randperm(n) where n is an integer number, I got an error message:

ERROR: UndefVarError: randperm not defined.

Presumably, I have not loaded a library that contains this function. So, could anyone please tell me which library should I load so that I can use that function? Thank you in advance!

Nha

Comment: If you're used to the syntax and idioms of v0.6, be aware the core devs are recommending that users work on v0.7 for a month or so, until they get used to all the breaking changes (which all generate descriptive warnings on v0.7, as others have mentioned below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load standard library `Random`, e.g.:

```
julia> using Random

julia> randperm(10)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  3
  7
 10
  2
  8
  5
  9
  4
  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That worked perfectly. I was wondering whether there is a document where I can see the load standard library for the function "randperm" as you mentioned. Thanks for your help! Nha

Comment: If you were on Julia 0.7 you would get a warning that this is what you should do. Additionally in the Julia Manual here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Random/#Random.randperm you see that `randperm` is defined in `Random` module (on the same page you can see that `rand` and `randn` for instance are defined as `Base.rand` which means that you do not need to import `Random` to use them).

Comment: This is very helpful and a fast answer, thank you,  Bogumił.

Comment: We really do need a "modules and exported functions" search built into the language though (or at least provided as part of pkg.julialang.org). There was talk of implementing such a feature at some point in the past, but I haven't followed what happened to that discussion ...

Comment: That would be great if we could have such search built into Julia. Additionally, I have another issue when installing the HDF5 module (see at  https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl/issues/500). Have you two ever encountered this issue? Or do you know how to fix it?